# How to replace * with a class CSS

Tags: css

I found this nice code which does something I like but the developer uses * to define some things and I would like to replace it with a class that will define only what the developer created but after I create a class wrapping his whole work around it, it simply doesn't work.

His version:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

My version:

```
.bar,
.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

My version simply doesn't work although theoretically I'm doing the same thing.

The original code: https://codepen.io/havardob/pen/zNPjeg

Comment: try `.bar *` instead (`.bar *,.bar *:before, .bar *:after`)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work either.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: what you want to do ? show us your code and how it's not working

Comment: Actually, reverted my answer. Can you provide a simple example where it isn't working so we can see how it isn't working?

Comment: Updated with the original code.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone has actually said this explicitly yet, so I will: '*' in css is a wild card, it matches any tag type. So that css is touching a lot of things. And trying to replicate it with a single class isn't trivial... Unless your Dom is super trivial.

Comment: @ZackRoberto - I tested at https://jsfiddle.net/n82Ld9tk/ All descendent elements have box-sizing set to border-box.

Comment: your code reflect nothing ...

Comment: We don't care about the original code. What are **you** doing that *isn't* working?

Comment: @AaronPool I understand that, which is why I would like to make it 'touch' only what I selected and not everything which messes up the rest of my code.

Comment: @Anthony I simply wrapped the <ul> into a div with a class named bar. That is all I'm changing and I would like for the effect inside the * to remain after I change it from * to my bar class.

Comment: Ah, well, in that case, Anthony's answer is what you're looking for, assuming you also want the style to apply to everything nested inside the element you've put your class on.

Comment: I tried all of his answers and unfortunately none of them worked.

Comment: The second you wrap it in a div, it goes sideways. It has nothing to do with your modification to the `*`. Try it yourself. Change it back to just `*`.

Comment: Put his answer in, save it to a codepen, then respond with the link. I'm pretty proficient in css, so I think either we're misunderstanding your request or you're misunderstanding our answer.

Comment: @AaronPool - check out my latest revision. The original CSS is just a little too generic (not using hardly any id or class selectors, only tag selectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is only setting that attribute on that wrapper element, not on every element inside the wrapper. Try this instead:

```
.bar, .bar *,
.bar::before, .bar *::before,
.bar::after,  .bar *::after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

For your specific example, the reason it isn't working is because the developer has a lot of other element-level rules in place. For example:

```
div {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
```

That is getting applied to *all* divs, including your wrapper div.

You would need to identify each of these and also append them with your class. So in the case of the above:

```
.bar div {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
```

Here is a fork of that example, but where I've appended any element-level selectors with `.bar`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GddXMy

Since the CSS is actually SCSS (in this example), you could also wrap most of it inside your class. So starting at:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
```

to the very end, you can change it to :

```
.foo {
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      position: absolute;
 // all the rest of the CSS
 }
```

Note that this is a benefit of SCSS allowing for nesting selectors inside of selectors, and wouldn't work with plain CSS.

Another fork:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oddPEZ

Comment: He want to replace * by a class so I think the intended result is to select only that element

Comment: No, I think he wants to have it be the same as the wildcard, but only for elements wrapped inside his class.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/stevensonmt/pen/OZZogv

```
.bar,
.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  }
```

That seems to work for me.

Comment: But this doesn't address the true spirit of the question, which is how to simply have the css get applied to elements inside his `.bar` div. Your solution requires a fuller grasp of what the third-party CSS is doing, which is admirable, but not going to always be the answer to anyone else running into similar scenarios.